# "could not load PEM client certificate LibreSSL error error:02FFF002:system" error when running curl on MacOS - stuck

Tags: curl, openssl, homebrew, macos-monterey, libressl

I seem to be completely stuck with my current MacOS system where I am simply unable to call a `curl` command without getting the following response:

```
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

A couple years back I remember doing quite a bit of configuration with OpenSSL and I'm wondering if this is related to the issues I'm finding now. Unfortunately, I cannot remember exactly what I changed.

It's impacting me significantly because there are a number of scenarios where I need to run a curl command. For example, more recently I've needed to run `curl -fsSL -k https://ionic.io/get-ionic-cloud-cli | bash` but I get the same error.

Is there a way for me to reset my configuration or does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this?